# strncmp to compare strings that may contain ints "1234"

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string input="42";

    const char* var1 = &input[0];
    const char* var2 = &input[1];
    if (1==strncmp(var1,var2,1)){cout<<"Not working"<<endl;}

}
```

I am trying to compare 4 and 2, the thing is the input may be a string such as "ab". I thought this function compared ascii values. That would mean that this function should work for my 42 but sadly doesn't as nothing is printed out:(

Comment: strncmp will return 0 if they are completely the same... nonzero otherwise, you probably want `srtnstr`

Comment: @GradyPlayer I think you mean `strnstr`

Comment: Why are you comparing the return value of `strncmp` to `1`?

Comment: If the goal is to simply compare two `char` values, you don't need to call a function at all, you can just say `if (input[0] == input[1]) {...}`

Comment: Why are you "trying to compare 4 and 2"? Can you give us a more general problem statement? `input[0]` and `input[1]` are `char` values (i.e., integers); why not just compare them?

Comment: to check whether the value input[0] is larger than input[1]

Comment: ... `input[0] > input[1]`?

Comment: You will need to use `std::string::c_str()` if you use `strncmp`.  There is no guarantee that `string[]` will return a pointer to a C-Style (nul terminated) array of characters.

Comment: Yeah, your right i can just compare the two char values directly. Thx

Comment: You should use something shorter:  `if (input[0] == input[1])` to compare characters.

Comment: See also:  `std::string::find` to find substrings.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `strncmp` doesn't require C strings as inputs.

Answer (score 2):

`strncmp` isn't guaranteed to return exactly `1` for "greater than". It just returns a positive value, so the condition should be `strncmp(...) > 0`.